# Plyr.js with Fancybox 3, multiple videos not initializing

Tags: jquery, fancybox-3, plyr.js

I am trying to implement multiple videos on the same page that open in lightboxes. I am currently using Plyr.js because it can skin html5, vimeo and youtube videos to all look the same. I am also using Fancybox for the lightbox.

When I add a single video, things seem to work. However, multiple videos don't seem to initialize in the lightbox. I've also noticed if I have a youtube video and make it first in the list, it works, but if it follows another video, it will not initialize.

I am using a class `.player` instead of an id since I have multiple instances.

I know this is a lightbox issue, because if I remove the lightbox all the videos work fine. So probably I need to somehow adjust how the lightbox is initializing the Plyr.js

Here is my code:

**Sample HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <p><a href="#video1" data-fancybox>HTML5 Video</a></p>
  <div id="video1" class="lightbox">
    <video controls crossorigin playsinline class="player">
    <!-- Video files -->
      <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-720p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
  <p><a href="#video2" data-fancybox>Youtube Video</a></p>
  <div id="video2" class="lightbox">
    <div class="player" data-plyr-provider="youtube" data-plyr-embed-id="bTqVqk7FSmY"></div>
  </div>
  <p><a href="#video3" data-fancybox>HTML5 Video</a></p>
  <div id="video3" class="lightbox">
    <video controls crossorigin playsinline class="player">
    <!-- Video files -->
      <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-720p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Sample JS:**

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
  beforeShow: function() {
    const player = new Plyr('.player', {});
  }
});
```

**Sample CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.lightbox {
  display: none;
  width: 600px;
}

.fancybox-content {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I know this is a lightbox issue

How can it be lightbox issue if it is working perfectly fine? I repeat - perfectly fine!

> multiple videos don't seem to initialize in the lightbox

Again, wrong assumption. If you would check `#video2` element, you would see that it is empty. Why? I'm not Plyr expert, but maybe it would not initialize into hidden elements. Try changing `beforeShow` to `afterShow` callback - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xQMmRV

Comment: In your example, video 1 and video 3 do not work correctly. They are playing but not as a Plyr.js video. You can tell because they don't automatically resize and don't have Plyr controls. This is the trouble I'm having, getting them ALL to work.

Comment: When I say the lightbox is an issue, not that the lightbox is not working, but getting player to initialize inside of the lightbox.

Comment: I repeat, lightbox shows empty content, because ... your element is empty. So, your issue is not related to the lightbox at all. Use developer tools to check contents of each element on the page before starting lightbox. Also, the issue that videos are not resized to fit correctly is issue of Plyr, too.

Comment: In your example, the HTML5 videos are not Plyr elements at all. They are not being initiated by Plyr and therefore are not being resized or using the controls of Plyr. You haven't provided a way to do what you are saying.

Comment: I tried to explain that lightbox does what you asked it to do. You created empty element and the lightbox displays it as it is. If you are having issue with 3rd party script, then you should ask about that instead.

Comment: Yeah and you are wrong. But since my question specifically asks about Plyr.js and you have no idea how to set it up, probably best for you to let someone else chime in here.

Comment: thanks this works for me

$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
  beforeShow : function() {
    const player = new Plyr('.fancybox-video');
  }